# CSS tabs not showing properly in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have used css to display tab with right side angle (wizard type). Its working fine with Chrome & IE 11. But in Mozilla Firefox its showing an additional line on the bottom side (see screen shot):

[image]

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LwdejrLm/

```css
.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tabs.three li {
  width: 31.4%;
}

.tabs.four li {
  width: 23%;
}

.tabs>li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  float: left;
}

.tabs>li+li {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.tabs>li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

.tabs>li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.tabs>li span {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #e04411;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs>li .tbno {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tabs>li:last-child .tbno {
  right: -30px;
}

.tabs>li .nav-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -30px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
  border-color: #fff #fff #fff #e04411;
  z-index: 150;
}

.tabs>li .nav-wedge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  border-color: #e04411 #eeeeee #e04411 transparent;
  z-index: 150;
}

.tabs>li.active .nav-arrow {
  border-color: #fff #fff #fff #444;
}

.tabs>li.active .nav-wedge {
  border-color: #444 #444 #444 transparent;
}

.tabs>li.active span {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .tabs.three li {
    width: 22%;
  }
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 22%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 18.5%;
  }
  .tabs>li span {
    padding: 11px 6px;
  }
  .tabs>li .tbno {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 17%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs four">
  <li><span>Booking</span>
    <div class="tbno">1</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Services</span>
    <div class="tbno">2</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Confirmation</span>
    <div class="tbno">3</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Payment</span>
    <div class="tbno">4</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just FYI, I also see undesired lines in Chrome. One red/black, one white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.tabs>li span` is `inline-block` element it inherits some properties  e.g. `line-height` from it's parent, so you need to reset it.

```
.tabs>li span{
  line-height: 1;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tabs.three li {
  width: 31.4%;
}

.tabs.four li {
  width: 23%;
}

.tabs>li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  float: left;
}

.tabs>li+li {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.tabs>li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

.tabs>li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.tabs>li span {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #e04411;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabs>li .tbno {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tabs>li:last-child .tbno {
  right: -30px;
}

.tabs>li .nav-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -30px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
  border-color: #fff #fff #fff #e04411;
  z-index: 150;
}

.tabs>li .nav-wedge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  border-color: #e04411 #eeeeee #e04411 transparent;
  z-index: 150;
}

.tabs>li.active .nav-arrow {
  border-color: #fff #fff #fff #444;
}

.tabs>li.active .nav-wedge {
  border-color: #444 #444 #444 transparent;
}

.tabs>li.active span {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .tabs.three li {
    width: 22%;
  }
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 22%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 18.5%;
  }
  .tabs>li span {
    padding: 11px 6px;
  }
  .tabs>li .tbno {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 17%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs four">
  <li><span>Booking</span>
    <div class="tbno">1</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Services</span>
    <div class="tbno">2</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Confirmation</span>
    <div class="tbno">3</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Payment</span>
    <div class="tbno">4</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes)

Comment: Yeah! Fine now... :)

Comment: You can read more about `inline-boxes` ***[here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes)***

Answer (score 2):

Just added reset css to your code and few edits it will render same view in all browsers.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
.tabs.three li {
 width: 31.4%;
}
.tabs.four li {
 width: 23%;
}
.tabs > li {
 position: relative;
 overflow: visible;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 border-left: 15px solid transparent;
 float: left;
}
.tabs > li + li {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.tabs > li:first-child {
 border-left: 0;
}
.tabs > li:last-child {
 border-right: 0;
}
.tabs > li span {
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: #e04411;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 12px 20px;
 color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
}
.tabs > li .tbno {
 position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
}
.tabs > li:last-child .tbno {
    right: -30px;
}
.tabs > li .nav-arrow {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: -30px;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
 border-color: #fff #fff #fff #e04411;
 z-index: 150;
}
.tabs > li .nav-wedge {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: -20px;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
 border-color: #e04411 #eeeeee #e04411 transparent;
 z-index: 150;
}
.tabs > li.active .nav-arrow {
 border-color: #fff #fff #fff #444;
}
.tabs > li.active .nav-wedge {
 border-color: #444 #444 #444 transparent;
}
.tabs > li.active span {
 background-color: #444;
 color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.tabs.three li {
 width: 22%;
}
.tabs.four li {
 width: 22%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
.tabs.four li {
 width: 20%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
.tabs.four li {
 width: 18.5%;
}
.tabs > li span {
 /*padding: 11px 6px;*/
}
.tabs > li .tbno {
 display:none;
}
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
.tabs.four li {
 width: 17%;
}
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs four">
  <li><span>Booking</span>
   <div class="tbno">1</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Services</span>
    <div class="tbno">2</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Confirmation</span>
    <div class="tbno">3</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Payment</span>
   <div class="tbno">4</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: which few edits? you should say which edits you made

Comment: on this media query:

@media (max-width: 640px) {

.tabs.four li {
 width: 18.5%;
}
.tabs > li span {
 /*padding: 11px 6px;*/  {not using this}
}
.tabs > li .tbno {
 display:none;
}

}

On this class just took out double padding:

.tabs > li span

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tabs.three li {
  width: 31.4%;
}

.tabs.four li {
  width: 23%;
}

.tabs>li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  float: left;
}

.tabs>li+li {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.tabs>li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

.tabs>li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.tabs>li span {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #e04411;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs>li .tbno {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tabs>li:last-child .tbno {
  right: -30px;
}

.tabs>li .nav-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -30px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 21px 10px 21px 20px;
  border-color: #fff #fff #fff #e04411;
  z-index: 150;
}

.tabs>li .nav-wedge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 21px 0 21px 20px;
  border-color: #e04411 #eeeeee #e04411 transparent;
  z-index: 150;
}

.tabs>li.active .nav-arrow {
  border-color: #fff #fff #fff #444;
}

.tabs>li.active .nav-wedge {
  border-color: #444 #444 #444 transparent;
}

.tabs>li.active span {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .tabs.three li {
    width: 22%;
  }
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 22%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 18.5%;
  }
  .tabs>li span {
    padding: 11px 6px; height:20px;
  }
  .tabs>li .tbno {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .tabs.four li {
    width: 17%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs four">
  <li><span>Booking</span>
    <div class="tbno">1</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Services</span>
    <div class="tbno">2</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Confirmation</span>
    <div class="tbno">3</div>
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-wedge"></div>
    <span>Payment</span>
    <div class="tbno">4</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use border-top or border-bottom with 21px

Comment: this is fine with firefox, but problem in chrome

Comment: @media (max-width: 640px)
js:125
.tabs>li span {
    padding: 11px 6px;
    height: 20px;
}

Answer (score 0):

`.tabs>li span` element's height is calculated as below:

`padding-top + line-height + padding-bottom` which equals to `11px + line-height + 11px`.
Since default value of `line-height` is normal, which diffs in browsers. So the final height of `.tabs>li span` is unsure. But arrow height is just `border-top-width + border-bottom-width` which is a fixed value(40px). Then when the height of `.tabs>li span` is bigger than 40px, it will cause the above effect.

So, you can just set `.tabs>li span` to `line-height: 18px`, which satisfy `11px + 18px + 11px = 40px`.